# Obtain user location on Android

Tags: android, geolocation, magnetometer

I would like to develop a metal detector app for Android and to do so i'm using the magnetometer alongside with the GeomagneticField native class. This is what i'm doing:

1. Retrieve x, y, z values from the magnetometer and calculate the magnetic field as x^2 + y^2 + z^2.
2. Calculate the Geomagnetic field using the only constructor given by the GeomagneticField class. To calculate my coordinates i'm using the Location manager and the other classes related to it.
3. Compare those magnetic fields to detect a metal.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener, LocationListener {

    SensorManager man;
    Sensor sensor;
    SensorEventListener thisActivity = this;
    double earthField;
    Location l;
    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        man = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensor = man.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);

        l = getLocation();
        if(l != null)
        {
            GeomagneticField gmf = new GeomagneticField((float) l.getLatitude(),
                    (float) l.getLongitude(),
                    (float) l.getAltitude(),
                    l.getTime());
            earthField = getEarthField(gmf);
        }
        else
        {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.debug)).setText("l è nullo");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        man.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        man.registerListener(thisActivity,
                sensor,
                Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];
        float magneticField = (float) getField(x, y, z);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.xreading)).setText("X: " + x + "");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.yreading)).setText("Y: " + y + "");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.zreading)).setText("Z: " + z + "");

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.earthTxt)).setText("Earth: " + earthField);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.fieldTxt)).setText("Calculated: " + magneticField);

        // I'm not sure i have to repeat this step inside OnSensorChanged.
        // Instructions inside the if statement are executed by onCreate, too.
        if(l != null)
        {
            GeomagneticField gmf = new GeomagneticField((float) l.getLatitude(),
                    (float) l.getLongitude(),
                    (float) l.getAltitude(),
                    l.getTime());
            earthField = getEarthField(gmf);
        }


        TextView metalNearby = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.metalNearby);

        if (magneticField > 1.4*earthField || magneticField < 0.6*earthField) {
            //there is a high probability that some metal is close to the sensor
            metalNearby.setText("Ho rilevato un metallo");
        }
        else {
            metalNearby.setText("Sto cercando...");
        }
    }

    private double getEarthField(GeomagneticField gmf) {
        return getField(gmf.getX(), gmf.getY(), gmf.getZ());
    }

    private double getField(float x, float y, float z) {
        return Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2) + Math.pow(z, 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) { }

    public Location getLocation()
    {
        Location location = null;
        try
        {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

            // Creating an empty criteria object
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

            try
            {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }
            catch (SecurityException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            return location;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        l = location;
    }
```

My problem is that the variable earthField always evaluates to 0.0 and this makes me think the method getLocation (user defined) always returns null. 
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you need new location every some time or every some traveled meters, try to use code like that:

```
public void getLocation() {
        try {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            boolean isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
            }

            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, mLocationListener);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

MIN_TIME - this time through as the system will receive location

MIN_DISTANCE - the same, only with a distance

mLocationListener - your listener where you get location

Comment: Your solution works. However, what is the right way to compare the values obtained from the magnetometer with the GeomagneticField object in order to detect metals?

Comment: Unfortunately I have bad informed in the logic of your process. On stackoverflow I found the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371777/how-to-detect-a-metal-using-magnetic-sensor-in-android-phone. As I understand it, an error in your method getField () to determine magnitute.